# Split flat file into sub files using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am receiving one big flat file which has data of 1, 2, 3 or more than 3 files data starting with header line and ending with trailer line.

I need to split these data into separate files as per data. I believe it's easy to do with a PowerShell script. What would it look like?

Comment: Need more information.  How big is this file, and what do your header and trailer lines look like?

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have reliable header and trailer patterns to match on, you could do something like this:

```
$header = ""
$body = ""
$trailer = ""

Get-Content bigflagfile.txt | Foreach-Object {
  if ($_ -match '<headerpattern>') {
    $header += $_;
  }
  elseif ($_ -match '<trailerpattern>') {
    $trailer += $_;
  }
  else {
    $body += $_;
  }
}

$header | Out-File headerfile.txt
$body | Out-File body.txt
$trailer | Out-File trailerfile.txt
```

It's a low-tech solution, and may be prohibitively slow or die altogether (this depends largely on your definition of "one big file"). It's not a bad first stab in the absence of more information though.